# Determining the date of tag creation in Bazaar

Tags: bazaar, release-management

Using Bazaar:

Is it possible to determine the date of when a revision was tagged? 
This will be useful for determining when code was released. 
Note, I'm not too interested in the date of the tagged revision, but rather when the revision was tagged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags are currently not first-class citizens in a Bazaar branch; their addition and removal isn't tracked in revisions. So no, I don't think you can ask anything about the history of a tag; once it changes, any previous state of that tag (including "wasn't there") is unavailable.

Comment: Note: tags should not be tracked in revisions. But there is/was intent to add extra information to tags, but bzr still lacks this feature.